# How do I bootstrap a node into chef server with "non root & non sudo" user?

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe, chef-solo, cookbook

I have a node(VM) with a non-root user which does not have sudo permissions too.
It will not be able to bootstrap the node since the non root non sudo user will have no access to /etc where the chef-client configuration files and cache reside.

Is it possible to achieve it with non root & non sudo user?
Or do we have any hack or alternative to do it?

Comment: Even if you forget about the Chef configuration, will a non-root/non-sudo user have permission to do the actual configuring you want to do with chef? i.e. if you're going to use Chef to install NTP, are you able to do that without sudo/root.

Comment: with a lot of pain and headaches customizing the bootstrap template, pointing to another directory for conf and using a path to the conf at each chef-client invocation, and as @Disco3 said, you'll enter a nightmare as a lot of resources assume to be root and will fail if not. Kind of masturbating with a cheese rapper, a lot of pain for few satisfactory result.

Comment: Well, I agree with you guys.
@Disco3 - Btw, we are not doing any tasks which will require root/sudo access. It is as simple as starting process as a user (non root - non sudo) for security concerns.
 
I do agree with Tensibai that it is not worth to achieve what I am looking for. Hence decided to bootstrap with sudo user and then switch user to non-root non-sudo user to accomplish tasks.
It was my curiosity to hear from community people like you guys before proceeding. 
Thank you! Appreciate it.

Answer (score 3):

You can technically just run `chef-client` as any user. As you noted you'll need to reconfigure a bunch of directories like where to put the client key and where to write logs but Chef itself doesn't care what user it runs as. I say "technically" because running the client as something other than root isn't usually very useful as it can't do very much.